# Segmentation fault when connecting a Signal and a Slot

Tags: qt, segmentation-fault, pyside

I've simplified my code to these lines:

```
#-*- coding:utf8 -*-

from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

table = QTreeView()
table.setModel( QStandardItemModel() )

@Slot(QItemSelection, QItemSelection)
def someSlot(selected, deselected):
    print "Slot Triggered"
    # do something ...

table.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(someSlot) # <-- error caused by this line !
```

When I try to connect a `Slot` to the `selectionChanged` `Signal`, I get a segmentation fault error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

something wrong in my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep `selectionModel` reference while the app is running:

```
#table.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(someSlot)
selectionModel = table.selectionModel()
selectionModel.selectionChanged.connect(someSlot)
```

Comment: I use PySide instead of PyQt, it always returns me a segmentation fault when i adapt your code with pyside functions.

Comment: Sorry, my first PySide experience. The solution is keep `selectionModel` reference while the app is running.